# Arithmetic Sequences finding the sum for $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$x+1, 3x+1, 6x-2$ are the first three terms of arithmetic sequence. What value of $n$ does the sum first exceed $100$?

How would you do this? Would you use $S = \frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)$?

The second part: The sum of the first three terms of a geometric sequence is 80640 and the sum of the 5th, 6th and 7th term is 315.

Calculate r and a and evaluate the sum to infinity

Comment: You would use that formula, but first you need to know what $a$ and $d$ are, and to find those numbers, you need to know what $x$ is. Hint: each term should be exactly $d$ more than the previous term.

Comment: That's right. But remember, $d$ is also the difference between the second and third term, so you can $d$ as another expression in terms of $x$. Find the value of $x$ that makes both expressions of $d$ equal.

Comment: Yes. Then solve for $x$. This should give you your value of $a$ and $d$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now that you have these numbers, plug them into the sum formula, and find the smallest value of $n$ so that $S > 100$.

Comment: Sn? I'm not sure what you mean by that. You're trying to find $n$ such that $100 < \frac{n}{2}(2 \times 4 + (n - 1) \times 6)$. I'm not sure what tools you have for this, but I think it shouldn't be too hard to do with trial and error.

Comment: @mikemike656: your sequence is not an aritmetich progression...

Comment: If it helps you, then please do, but I don't think you should need to. Try using your calculator to plug in some small, specific values of $n$, until you find one where $\frac{n}{2}(2 \times 4 + (n - 1) \times 6)$ exceeds $100$.

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question, rather than just add another question onto the current one. If you send me a message when you do, I can take a look at it.

Comment: I see. OK, the first three terms of a geometric sequence are $a$, $ar$, and $ar^2$. So, you know $a + ar + ar^2 = 80640$. The fifth, sixth, and seventh terms are, respectively, $ar^4, ar^5, ar^6$, and their sum is $315$. What happens if you take the first equation, and multiply both sides by $r^4$?

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are three consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression then $a+c=2b$ ie the middle term is the average of the terms on either side - useful to know. I am sure you can prove it.

Comment: I did not, actually. I found $n$ to be $6$.

Comment: You would get the sum, $ar^4 + ar^5 + ar^6 = 80640r^4$. But, $ar^4 + ar^4 + ar^6$ also equals something else...

Comment: That's right. Now, solve for $r$. Note: there will be a positive and a negative solution (but I'm guessing whoever wrote the question was only thinking about positive $r$).

Comment: Now, find $a$. You know $r$, and a couple of equations in terms of $r$ and $a$, so you should be able to find it. (Note, you're ignoring the $r = -1/4$ solution, which I'm fine with so long as you're fine with it.)

Comment: Exactly @mikemike656

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Now, compute the infinite sum.

Comment: That's right, good job! FYI, I'm not going to answer more questions if you edit this question. :-)

Comment: :) That's fine. Thank you for your help. I really do appreciate it and i hope you have a great day :)

Comment: You too! ${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we workshopped in the comments, we need to first find the value of $x$ so that this becomes an arithmetic sequence. In order to be an arithmetic sequence, there needs to be a common difference $d$ between the terms. The difference between the first and second terms is
$$d = (3x + 1) - (x + 1) = 2x.$$
The same number should be the difference between the second and third terms:
$$d = (6x - 2) - (3x + 1) = 3x - 3.$$
Therefore, we must have
$$3x - 3 = 2x \implies x = 3.$$
So, $d = 2x = 6$. The first term, $a$, is $a = x + 1 = 4$.

The sum of the first $n$ terms of the arithmetic sequence is given by the formula
$$S_n = \frac{n}{2}(2a + (n - 1)d) = \frac{n}{2}(2 \times 4 + (n - 1) \times 6) = n(3n + 1).$$
We need to find the smallest $n$ such that $100 < S_n = n(3n + 1)$. After some trial and error, we see $S_5 = 80 < 100$, but $S_6 = 114 > 100$, so the answer is $n = 6$. (Note that, since $d$ is positive, $S_n$ will increase as $n$ increases, so there's no way that there's a smaller $n$ such that $S_n > 100$.)